# Some unicode characters not working with drawtext in FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

When using some unicode characters as text in `drawtext`, like emojis the characters will be replaced by rectangles. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Use a font that contains the characters?

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm using 'Arial Unicode'

Comment: And does Arial Unicode contain the emojis?

Comment: It would appear not since it 'fails' for those characters. I've tried 'Apple Color Emoji' but that does not work either. Do you know of any fonts that support emoji?

Comment: No. Search for "fonts supporting emoji" would seem the obvious thing to start with, especially when you haven't provided your operating system ...

Comment: Using the correct font makes no difference. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/374046/cannot-render-non-ascii-characters-with-ffmpegs-drawtext